# Pinescript question: normalize two things, divide, and plot

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to do the following:
First variable is whatever asset is in the main window.
Second variable is always dxy.

Essentially the thing I'm after is a correlation. For example, SPX/DXY correlation. When the correlation is above a specified (variable) value I can set in the settings, I want the plotted line to be green; when it is below the specified value, I want it to be red (or whatever color I want, chosen in the settings).

I want the number it spits out to be something between zero and one, ie, normalized, to each candle in the window, and for this to work across all available time scales.

I have no idea where to even start here. I'm a old fart who used to be a chemist. (At least I know how to type.....)

Anyway....
I have tried various things such as the following.

```
// Fetching data for BTC and dxy
BTC = security("COINBASE:BTCUSD", "D", close)
dxy = security("TVC:DXY", "D", close)


// Normalizing BTC and dxy

 norm_dxy = (dxy - sma(dxy, 10)) / stdev(dxy, 10)
 norm_BTC = (BTC - sma(BTC, 10)) / stdev(BTC, 10)
 ratio1 = norm_BTC / norm_dxy

// Plotting the data in a separate sub-chart
plot(ratio1, title="ratio", color=color.red)
```

The problem is that's not right. (I'm just putting sma because it's a function I know.)
What I really need is a way that can give me the min value for each variable, and the max value for each too (since the formula for standardization is norm_dxy = (dxy_at_any_point - dxymin)/(dxymax-dxymin)

I looked at math.min and ta.lowest but see no way to distinguish betwween the two instruments.
The other thing I can't figure out is how to instead of hard-calling BTC just call whatever instrument I'm looking at, at least not without breaking everything else.

Can someone help here?

I said what I tried above. Was expecting a number between 0 and 1 that I could plot.

I have no idea how to make the drawn line green if above a settable value and red if it's below.